# Solving transcendental equation involving exponential function

Tags: special-functions, transcendental-equations

I want to find analytical solutions of the equation
$$(αx+β)=δe^{γx}, \qquad (1)$$ which is exactly this one:
[Solving transcendental equation involving exponential functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440748/solving-transcendental-equation-involving-exponential-functions)

The substitution
$y = -\gamma x - \beta \gamma / \alpha$ 
transforms it into $$ y = \mu \cdot e^{-y}, \qquad (2)$$
where $\mu = -\gamma/\alpha \cdot e^{-\gamma \beta/\alpha}$.

When $\mu \geq 0 $, this equation has only one root, because functions $z = y$ and $z = \mu e^{-y}$ intersect in one point. Then I can treat this root as a funtion of $\mu$, that is $y = f(\mu)$.
I can expand this function into the series about $\mu = 0$ by differentiating (2) and treating $y$ as an implicit function of $\mu$.
I have a feeling though, that this is a reinvenging of wheel, and $y(\mu)$ must be a well-known special function.

Can someone point me to right direction where I can find an analytical representation of $y(\mu)$ through known (special) functions?

Comment: I don't think you can you can get a numerical solution though.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. This is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Dylan, thank you a lot. This is what I looked for! Indeed, (2) can be written as $y\cdot e^{y} = \mu$ and therefore $y=W(\mu)$. How can I mark your comment as an answer or at lease vote it up?

Comment: I'll post the comment as an answer

Comment: Note that  Lambert W function
guarantees that
there are always two distinct real solutions
for $\mu\in(-\frac1e,0)$.  
See also [Time for a new elementary function?](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27858540).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation

$$ y e^y = \mu $$

Has the solution in the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

$$ y = W(\mu) $$

which is just defined as the inverse of the function
$$ f(y) = ye^y $$

For $ -1/e < \mu < 0 $ the inverse is not one-to-one and you get two real solutions.

There does exist a Taylor series of the main branch ($y \ge -1$) around $0$ that converges for $-1/e < \mu < 1/e $

$$ W_0(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n $$

For larger values you get a rather complicated series involving $\ln x$ and $\ln(\ln x)$. Details are all in the Wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting back in Dylan's answer.  The solution $x$ to
$$
\alpha x+\beta = \delta e^{\gamma x}
$$
is
$$
x = -{\frac {1}{\gamma\alpha} \left( \alpha\,W \left(-{\frac {
\delta\gamma}{\alpha}{e^{-{{\beta\gamma}/{\alpha}
}}}}\right)+\beta\,\gamma \right) }
$$
using the Lambert W function.